# Custom Appender in Log4j2 not recieving any logs

Tags: java, kotlin, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have set up a custom appender that will log to memory here it is below

```
@Plugin(name = "MemoryAppender",
        category = Core.CATEGORY_NAME,
        elementType = Appender.ELEMENT_TYPE)
class InMemoryAppender(name: String,
                       filter: Filter?) : AbstractAppender(name, filter, null, true, Property.EMPTY_ARRAY) {

    companion object {
        @PluginFactory
        @JvmStatic
        fun createAppender(
                @PluginAttribute("name") name: String,
                @PluginElement("Filter") filter: Filter?): InMemoryAppender {
            return InMemoryAppender(name, filter)
        }
    }

    private val buffer = CircularOverwritingBuffer(allowNonPowerOfTwoSizedBuffer = false)

    override fun append(event: LogEvent?) {
        event?.let {
            buffer.add("[${event.level}] ${DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(Instant.now())} ${event.message.formattedMessage}")
        }
    }

    fun inOrder(numberOfItems: Int): Iterator<String> {
        return buffer.emitInOrder(numberOfItems).iterator()
    }
}
```

And I have added it to my root logger in my log4j conf file, first by creating the appender

```
 <appenders>
     .... other appenders
     <MemoryAppender name="In-Memory-Appender"/>
 </appenders>
```

and then loaded it into the root logger

```
 <Loggers>
     <Root level="${defaultLogLevel}">
         .... opther appenders
         <AppenderRef ref="In-Memory-Appender"/>
     </Root>
 </Loggers>
```

However when I now get a logger for a class like this, I get nothing in my buffer

```
private val log = loggerFor<AClass>()
// or
private val log = contextLog()
```

But if I get the logger like so I can

```
LoggerContext.getContext().rootLogger.info("REQUESTING LOGS")
```

How do I make my appender capture the logs correctly?

Answer (score 0):

My Question was solved by the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21336499/2341393

The problem was an incorrect logger context being returned, and that slf4j was wrapping the Log4J Logger.